# Saving memory with Pandas bi-temporal DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory-management

I often need to construct a bi-temporal Pandas DataFrame, with `[CURR_DATE, HIST_DATE]` as MultiIndex, and a dozen columns of numerical, categorical and text data. Note for every `CURR_DATE`, the `HIST_DATE` will cycle through, say, 3 years, and the rest of the row largely depend on `HIST_DATE` describing information on the `HIST_DATE`, with very infrequent changes (due to information on that `HIST_DATE` get updated on certain `CURR_DATE`).

As you can see, this DataFrame has lots of repeated information. But it gets copied again and again, making the entire DataFrame very memory inefficient. (Comparatively, `dict` object would allow references hence pointing to the same underlying object to be highly efficient.)

Question: what would be a better way to construct the DataFrame to still allow bi-temporal processing ability (eg. `DATA_DATE` needs to be joined with some other DataFrame, and `HIST_DATE` needs to be joined with a 3rd DataFrame), while making the entire DataFrame a lot more memory efficient / having a much smaller memory footprint?

(Feel free to ask me to clarify if the question is not clear.)

Comment: Can you clarify what type of data is being stored in the "many, many columns" with often repeated data?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I added some clarification. Thank you.

Comment: Did my answer help?